# Printing document in embedded Google Docs Viewer from parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-docs

I'm using Google Docs Viewer to embed various documents on a page. I am able to manually focus the embedded iframe and ctrl+p to initiate a print, which the iframe handles appropriately. The problem is that there is no actual print button on the embedded viewer, so anyone not aware of the keyboard shortcut may have trouble printing the document.

I attempted to add a link on the parent that focused the iframe and then sent a print(), but the command was picked up by the parent rather than the iframe itself.

Do I have any options for issuing a print command to the embedded viewer?